# Trouble with modules || boolean in js and expressjs

Tags: javascript, express, web, boolean

Having strange trouble. I am trying to fix that for 2 days, but no success. Can you help me?

```js
commands.js
module.exports = function Say() {
  var Web = require('../web/web.js');
  if(Web.x === true){
      console.log('Doneee');
    }
  }


web.js
app.post('/main', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    var saycontent = req.body.say;
    console.log(saycontent);
    exports.x = true;
    var Sayy = require('../modules/commands.js');
    var say = new Sayy();
    say.Say;
    res.render('main', {qs: res.query});
  });
  app.listen(5000);
}
```

Why doesnt it show in console "Doneee"? Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

say.Say is a function, did you try invoking it? say.Say()

Comment: Yes. Here is a result( server cannot start because of some error)
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5000

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by my own.